# angularjs injection/dependency error

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I know it's an error on my part wiring it up and I've tried several different ways with the same result, injection error. Here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/willtx/XZ3sX/1/ the has what I'm trying to wire up ( BUT it is broken there as well, not throwing an error or anything), my apologies. I'm pretty green here. It seems straight forward but....

This is the error when it executes. If I remove the code the page starts working again.
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootscopeProvider <- $rootscope <- AddressBroadcastService

AddressBroadcastService's function is to allow other controllers to kickoff/react to an address verification. Here's an example of one of the other controllers that will react to the braodcast.

```
<div ng-controller="AddressCheckerController">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="AddressCheck.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Address Verification</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            Address to verify:<br />
            {{selectedRow.address}}
        </p>
        <span>Addresses found:</span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="address in modalItems">
                <a ng-click="selected.modalItem =  address">{{ address }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selectedAddress }}</b>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
     </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

I'm wide open to suggestions if I'm way off base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line you are creating a module `myApp` while injectcing `angularStart.services`

```
var appRoot = angular.module('myApp', ['angularStart.services']);
```

In this line you are trying to create a module `angularStart.services while injecting nothing

```
var angularStartServices = angular.module('angularStart.services');
```

The second one should be:

```
var angularStartServices = angular.module('angularStart.services', []);
```

if you pass one parameter to angular.module it is a get reference to a module function if you pass two it is a module creation call

Other things I found:

- must inject `ngResource` into your `appRoot` module
- and in order to inject `ngResource` you must include a reference to the `angular-resource` js file
- `$rootscope` should be `$rootScope`

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Brocco/XZ3sX/2/) w/ these chnage

Comment: Ha, thank you @Brocco! I've been looking at this too long. I'm going to take a break and hit it again. You got me 1 step closer. Thanks!